# Detect color on screen for Android

Tags: android, image, colors

1. Is there a program for Android which can detect `pixel color` on screen and make a click event to that x, y coordinates?
2. What is optimal algorithm to detect color on some area and get that pixel coordinates (if program not exist)?

This peace of program detect color on 400x400 pixels area:

```
//Set aim color
var rgb = 197137164;

//Init x,y pixels
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var ex = 0;

:myloop
for(x; x<400; x++)
{
   for(y;y<400;y++)
   {
      if(getcolor(x,y) == rgb)
      {
        RaiseEvent(x,y);
        set ex = 1;           
        break;
      }
      if(ex == 1){break;}
   }        
}
sleep(10000); 
set x = 0;
set y = 0;
set ex = 0;
goto myloop;
```

But this algorithm works slow I guess. I need to optimize this algorithm, but for now I don't know how. Any ideas? Or any programs exists already and I don't need to create bicycle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
Try out not getting each pixel one by one, instead use the getpixels() method, and iterate through the pixels array, it's really a lot faster then getting pixels on by one.

So when you got that one dimensional pixel array, you can iterate through it.

Let's assume you have 400x200 pixel (80000). So you iterate through the pixels with a for cycle, and check the pixels' color whether it matches the one you search for.
Something like this:

```
var coordinate;
for(int i=0; i<pixels.length;i++){
    if(pixel[i] == yourcolor){
       coordinate=i;
       break;
    }
}
var coordX = coordinate%400; //coordinate X = which column
var coordY = coordinate/200; //coordinate Y = which row
```

So if the matching pixel is the 400th, it will be the first pixel in the second row (as indexing is from 0 -> 0-399 = first row, 400-799 = second row and so on).

Prev assumption:

I suppose it's slow because it sleeps 10000 ms, delete that command.

```
sleep(10000);
```

Also I'd suggest not to put multiple commands in one line.

Comment: No, sleep(1000) for delay when color found. It's executed only one time. For example, you found some object and click on it, and you need some time wait for another detection. That's why there is sleep(1000).

Comment: I edited with sleep in another place, but it's doesn't matter. Just for better view, not optimization.

Comment: Why do you need that sleep() anyways?

Comment: Yes, getPixels() method is good optimization. And insteat call getcolor 16000 times, I'll call getpixels one time. But it still will compare 16000 times my etalon value (if didn't find earlier). If object has width 4px same color, maybe I need loop each 4th px, instead each 1px.

Comment: I need sleep to wait after color found. My bot should do some stuff, when find the color, after start loop again.

Comment: Could you write peace of code do demonstrate how to get needed coordinat using getpixels() array. For example: I will use getpixels(), than loop through array, and find etalon color. But how I would know which pixel(coordinates) belong that color, if I have only pixels colors without coordinates?

Comment: iterate thourgh the pixels array, and save the coordinate of the array which will be a number. I extend my answer recording this.

Comment: I'm sorry which language is your original code? As I've written mine first in java, and I don't know whether the % operator is available in yours. The main point is you'll need modulo 400 for coordX.

Comment: Alright, I get a point. Thank you. It seems easy. Wonder, that programs like color clikcer not exist on android.

Comment: I used hiroMacro programm with some script language and there only getcolor() func, there no getallpixels func, so I need use java under Android anyway. Or try optimaze somehow script with getcolor. Maybe get not each pixel, but each 4th or more(depend on width same color of object)